# Redirect specific urls from old domain to new domain and retain parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Here is a sample old URL:
`https://www.olddomain.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=calendar&month=8&year=1904&catid=39&Itemid=339`

Which needs to be redirected to:
`https://www.newdomain.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=calendar&month=8&year=1904&catid=39&Itemid=339`

Since there are countless month,year,catid,and itemid I wanted to catch them all with one rule.

I was trying to create a htaccess redirect for any URL that has `"/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=calendar"`.

This was my best attempt:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=calendar(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=calendar$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=calendar [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure this your topmost rule and you refresh your browser cache before testing this rule.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  (Learn something new every day) Thank you.